# AngularJs scope variable not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have in my controller:

```
$scope.items = myItems;
var myItems = [{title=""}]
```

but on my view nothing gets displayed, if i set the $scope.items to equal the list it works fine.
Eventually i want to be able to change the list used when i user clicks a div on my view. i will be using this statement to switch

```
$scope.toggle = function (tog) {
    if (tog == 0) {
        $scope.items = myItems;
    } else if (tog  == 1) {
        $scope.items = companyItems;
    };
};
```

Comment: you have syntax error here `var myItems = [{title=""}]`

Comment: `var myItems = [{title:""}]`

Comment: and also you assign value to `$scope.items` before assigning to `myItems`, so `$scope.items` is _undefined_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You have a syntax error, it should be `:` and not `=` inside the object. So:

   ```
   var myItems = [{title:""}]
   ```
2. Second, when you assign it in the order you do, `myItems` is not defined yet when assigning into the scope variable, so your value would be `undefined`. (at least in the initial run, after the `$scope.toggle` function is called, it will be okay. Just switch the 2 top lines around